# Default workflow status is not updating in workflow history

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, out-of-the-box

If i keep any manual logs in the workflow i am able to see those logs in the workflow history but the default logs of the Assign task are not logging in the workflow history.

Could you please let me know any ideas.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sharepoint provides this facility of deleting the workflow history. Ask your admin of any such timer job.

Here, we can select that with which frequency we can delete the workflow status.

[image: Image with the settings feature]

Comment: I think you understood the question wrong if i put any logs i can see those in workflow history but if i assign a task it should save the task assigned data to workflow history list but it not saving it in workflow history. This is SharePoint online there is no Timer Job to do changes by Admin.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to see exactly.

But I the task related data will be saved in "Tasks" list associated with your workflow, not in workflow history list.

Comment: does this answers your question?

Answer (score 0):

It is SharePoint designer workflow so you need to write log("any information").
Without writing this no log should be displayed.
Whereas in ootb workflow you get log when task is assigned.